# FPDF AddFont() - normal and bold version

Tags: fpdf

I successfully converted and imported a TTF file

```
$pdf->AddFont('ForoMed','','ForoMed.php');
```

The normal version works perfectly:

```
$pdf->SetFont('ForoMed', '', 11);
```

However, I seem to be unable to use the font in bold style:

```
$pdf->SetFont('ForoMed', 'B', 11);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bold version of a font has to be converted and imported separately. The second parameter of the `AddFont` method sets the style. The import of the bold version will look like this:

```
$pdf->AddFont('ForoMed','B','ForoMed_bold.php');
```